Is it possible to find the solution to a homogeneous second order ODE in terms of a known particular solution to the nonhomogeneous?
Using variation of parameters, you can find a particular solution to a second order ODE in terms of a known solution to the homogeneous. I'd like to find the opposite though, a solution to the homogeneous second order ODE given a known particular solution. I'm at a loss on how to proceed and could use some advice.
I have a solution to an equation that looks like
$$y(x)'' + f(x) y(x)' + g(x) y(x) = h(x)$$
But I'd like to find a solution to
$$y(x)'' + f(x) y(x)' + g(x) y(x) = 0$$
I know this is super general, I'm just looking for patterns and methods. Thank you in advance.

If you know two linearly independent functions that satisfy your homogeneous equation you need only two boundary conditions to write the fundamental solution, see my answer here.

Part of the issue I'm running into is that my solution is in the form of an exponential and only the exponential, but I've tried it several times and it does solve the equation $y'' + fy' + gy = h$ But In order to get this, I should be expecting something of the form $y = C1 y1 + C2 y2$ where $y1$ and $y2$ are solutions to the homogeneous form, I'm stuck though. I can get $y2$ in terms of $y1$ but even with my solution to the nonhomogenous, I can't find $y1$.

What software do you use?

Try with reduction of order.

Any method for doing that would also be a method for solving any given homogeneous equation. Given a homogeneous equation $L[y]=0$, take any nonzero function $y_1$and it is a particular solution of the nonhomogeneous equation $L[y]=L[y_1]$.

@user14111 I'm not familiar with this terminology, chance you can shoot me a reference to some definitions?
I'll give reduction of order, but I think I've seen a hole in my premise. If you set $y$ and plug in anything, you could call whatever remains the h(x). To that end, I don't think there's really a solution to be found in this method. That said, I do all my math by hand, usually two or three times to make sure I'm still correct. If I'm using a computer, I use my notes app and a notation I developed to make it more simple. When I think I have something, I write it up in TeX to check.

@TinyTim $L[y]$ is just an abbreviation for $y''+f(x)y'+g(x)y$, the left side of your equation, and what I was trying to say was just what you said in your comment: by plugging in a known function $y_1$ for $y$ you can manufacture nonhomogeneous equations with known particular solutions, so what you are asking for would be a universal remedy for homogeneous equations.

Hm... I did find out that if you have the equation $y'' - f(x) y' - f(x)' y = 0$, then a solution to this is $y = e^{f(x)}$, which is a neat solution where $L[y]$ has a kind of generalization applied. But beyond that...
